# update post meta for checkbox in the admin when inserted in the front-end

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta, metabox, wp-insert-post

Here's my problem, I allow a certain user type to create custom post type in the front-end of my site, with the  `wp_insert_post()` function... users can put values within a form and there's couple of input types, checkboxes, ranges, numbers, and text fields. 
But I have a problem with checkbox and radio inputs. when users save values, they don't appear in the post in the admin panel, I think the problem is in the `update_post_meta()` condition... 
here how was the condition:

```
     if( isset( $_POST[ 'checkbox_1' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'checkbox_1', 'yes' );
     }else{
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'checkbox_1', '' ); 
     }
```

so I changed it like that:

```
$stored_meta= get_post_meta($post_id);

     if(isset( $_POST[ 'checkbox_1' ] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'checkbox_1', $_POST[ 'checkbox_1' ]) ;
     }else{
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'checkbox_1', $stored_meta['checkbox_1'][0]); 
     }
```

Now they appear, but it's impossible to modify them in the admin panel, for example if user checked an input, even if I unchek it, it remains check after update.

I have tried other logic, but they all failed.

here's how look my checkbox input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value='yes' <?php if ( isset ( $stored_meta['checkbox_1'][0] ) ) checked( $stored_meta['checkbox_1'][0], 'yes'); ?>>
```

Comment: Well, by updating it to what's in $stored_meta, it looks like you're making it so if it's unchecked, it won't change, while if it is checked, it will change. Your first one really does look right... What if you change the `$stored_meta['checkbox_1'][0]` to `'no'`?

Comment: Checkboxes always throw me for a loop eventually because there's no negative to them. They're either there in the $_POST var with the yes value, or entirely missing. I often end up using 2 radios for a yes/no response instead, with one automatically selected.

Comment: so I have to make 2 inputs for every checkbox? and for one of those, put no as value, and set it as default? isn't it?

Comment: I have tried, it doesn't work, it still does not display the values ​​passed in front-end. 
When I get a ```var_dump(get_post_meta($post-ID))``` in the admin side, ```[checkbox_1][0] = 'no' ```. however it is a ```'yes'``` which was passed. it's like the post is updated before modification.

Comment: I use your radio trick instead and it works... Thanks.
 so all I have to do now is to create a toggle switch.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to WordPress SO.

You may already have solved the issue as suggested by @Stevish, but just in order to avoid promoting the idea of checkboxes somehow being bad or difficult, I'd like to point out, that they're perfectly okay and logical. :)

What is the problem in your first snippet, is the additional closing square bracket ']' in the value, which would cause a syntax error and thus PHP Fatal error.

Change this:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'checkbox_1', 'yes'] );
```

to this:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'checkbox_1', 'yes' );
```

Also, a handy way to deal with single value metadata is to specify the `$key` and the `$single` parameter like this:

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'checkbox_1', true );
```

That way you get the single value, and not an array where your value is the [0]. That way you can skip many `if( isset( $meta['whatever'][0] ) )` kind of checks. :)

Comment: Oh man! I looked over and over at his code and could NOT find any errors! Good eye!

Comment: That happens :) A good IDE will catch most of those.

Comment: this error wasn't in my code actually. As I said I tried many logic, and the first one wasn't no longer in my code, for the purpose of this post, I modified the code here to meet my explanation, and I guess made the error here... sorry!

Comment: thanks for the clue about the single parameter, I used it, but completely forgot it at this point